# Promise on AngularJS resource save action

Tags: javascript, html, rest, angularjs

I am currently working on a REST + AngularJS application.

I have a little problem concerning promises on resource save action.

My Factory:

```
App.factory('Course', function($resource) {
    var course = $resource('/AppServer/admin/courses/:courseId', {}, {});

    course.findAll = function() {
        return course.query();
    };

    course.findById = function(id) {
        return course.get({
            courseId : id
        });

    };

    course.saveCourse = function(course) {
        return course.$save();
    }

    return course;
});
```

My Controller:

```
App.controller('CourseEditController', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Course, FlashMessage) {
    // load course into edit form
    $scope.course = Course.findById($routeParams.courseId);

    // save edited course and print flash message
    $scope.saveCourse = function() {
        var savedCourse = Course.saveCourse($scope.course);

        savedCourse.$then(function(httpResponse) {
            FlashMessage.set("Die Änderungen am Kurs <i>" + savedCourse.title + "</i> wurden erfolgreich gespeichert.");
            $location.path("/kurse/verwalten");
        });
    }
});
```

Now the problem is, that I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method '$then' of undefined
```

The strange thing is that If I add the same then-callback to one of the finders (e.g. findById) everything works fine. But the return value of "return course.$save()" is undefined, compared to the return value of "return course.get({courseId:id});" which is "Object object".

What I want is to set the FlashMessage when the save action was fully executed and not before that.

Any ideas on this? The response from my REST service is correct. It returns the saved object.

Greets
Marc

Comment: are you calling the good course.$save() ? There is the `course` from $resource and the one from parameters. `course.saveCourse = function(course)`

Comment: I am calling the one from the params. Is that wrong? Or how could the other one (from the resource) know what to save?

Comment: Hi, This is totally unrelated to the question but just wondering which FlashMessage library are you using. Does it flash alert message even when the state has changed? Will remove this comment later.

Answer (score 42):

There is two slightly different API's, one for working with a resource instance and - in lack of better words - more generic version. The main difference beeing the use of `$`-prefixed methods (`get` vs `$get`)

The `$`-prefixed methods in [ngResource/resource.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0rc1/src/ngResource/resource.js#L523). proxies the call and returns the promise directly.

AFAIK before the resource gets instanciated, you can only access resources with the normal `get`.

```js
var promise = Resource.get().$promise;

promise.then(function(res)  { console.log("success: ", res); });
promise.catch(function(res) { console.log("error: ", res); });
```

With instanciated resource the `$`-prefixed methods are available:

```js
var res = new Resource({foo: "bar"});

res.$save()
    .then(function(res)  { console.log("authenticated") })
    .catch(function(req) { console.log("error saving obj"); })
    .finally(function()  { console.log("always called") });
```

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but any combination of save, $save, then and $then doesn't work and results in an error. I am using 1.0.8 Are you sure it's supposed to work like that?

Comment: is `Resource.$get()` the same as `Resource.get().$promise` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at angular documentation on [resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) it mentions

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data.

This may very well means that your call to $save would return empty reference. Also `then` is not available on Resource api before Angular 1.2 as resources are not `promise` based.

You should change your `saveCourse` method call to accept a function parameter for success and do the necessary action there.

Answer (score 1):

**This is for Angularjs 1.0.8**

In my service I have the following:

```
angular.module('dataProvider', []).
  factory('dataProvider', ['$resource','$q',function($resource,$q) { 
//....
var Student = $resource('/app/student/:studentid',
    {studentid:'@id'}
);
    return {
      newStudent:function(student){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var s = new Student({name:student.name,age:parseInt(student.age)});
        s.$save(null,function(student){
            deferred.resolve(student);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
}]);
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.createStudent=function(){
  dataProvider.newStudent($scope.newStudent).then(
    function(data){
      $scope.students.push(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: `$save` returns an object with promise methods. You could avoid creating an additional deferred object by just writing `return s.$save();`.

Comment: @jbielick It's a long time ago, I think I added that code to return a promise because 1.0.8 didn't.  https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/blob/master/1.0.8/angular-resource.js (line 420) compared to https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/blob/master/1.2.9/angular-resource.js (line 574)

Answer (score 0):

I added a method in controller to enable a resource have a promise when it executes a CRUD operation.

The method is the following:

```
function doCrudOpWithPromise(resourceInstance, crudOpName){
            var def=$q.defer()
            resourceInstance['$'+crudOpName](function(res){def.resolve(res)}, function(err){def.reject(err)})
            return def.promise
}
```

An invocation example is:

```
var t=new MyResource()
doCrudOpWithPromise(t,'save').then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late responde but you can have callabck on $save...

```
var savedCourse = Course.saveCourse($scope.course);

savedCourse.$save(function(savedCourse, putResponseHeaders) {
    FlashMessage.set("Die Änderungen am Kurs <i>" + savedCourse.title + "</i> wurden erfolgreich gespeichert.");
    $location.path("/kurse/verwalten");
});
```