# Get real response of ngResource save()

Tags: json, angularjs, ngresource

I have the following situation:

I use ngResource to save some data to the mysql database and after the successfull save() I want to log the json response the server sends to me:

```
Document.save({}, postData, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

This does not result in a simple response, but in something like an object with its own methods. I want some smple output like the `response.data` after an `$http.$get`:

```
{
    "docClass":"testets",
    "colCount":1,
    "columns":null,
    "groupid":7,
    "id":19,
    "lang":"de",
    "title":"test",
    "version":1409849088,
    "workflow":"12234"
}
```

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer
[Promise on AngularJS resource save action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131643/promise-on-angularjs-resource-save-action)

So I think in your case you need to do

```
var document = new Document(postData);
document.$save()
    .then(function(res){});
```

But also from the link I provided

> This may very well means that your call to $save would return empty reference. Also then is not available on Resource api before Angular 1.2 as resources are not promise based.

Comment: The solution you gave does not work. I get the same result as the one when I did it my way.